# What is the recommended method to create a speed meter graph in Android?

Tags: android, charts, androidplot

I'd like to create a chart similar to this

[image]

I'm considering using Android's [2-D graphics API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) with the classes **android.graphics.Canvas** and **android.graphics.Paint** for doing that, using Canvas's method [drawLine()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) to draw the segments on the border.

Alternatively, is there a chart libary that could help programming this kind of chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SpeedView](https://github.com/anastr/SpeedView), it has several different types of speedometers:

[image]

To make it work, add the dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.github.anastr:speedviewlib:1.1.7'
```

Then simply add view to your `XML` layout:

```
<com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.SpeedView
    android:id="@+id/speedView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You can set speed on gauge with the next code:

```
SpeedView speedometer = findViewById(R.id.speedView);
speedometer.speedTo(50);
```

Comment: @HugoGresse I've changed my code.

Comment: great thanks for the explaination